# Uncaught TypeError: $.blockUI is not a function

Tags: jquery, push-notification, jquery-blockui

i will call blockui funcation on external other js but its erro 
Uncaught TypeError: $.blockUI is not a function

Comment: You need to post your javascript. Also, did you import the libraries *before* your script?

Comment: First learn [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)